# Average an image

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Here is an image:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Hello,    %
%    world! %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

But it is too confusing for our undersized brains to compute. So we average it like this:

1. Split it into 2 x 2 sections. If the picture ends before a section is complete, imagine that there are spaces there.
2. Average the values of the ASCII characters in each section.
3. Round this average and convert it to an ASCII character.
4. Finally, replace all characters in the section to the average character.

Repeat this for all sections.

So the average of the image above looks like this:

```
$$>>II99######
$$>>II99######
$$##88KKGG####
$$##88KKGG####
```

**Your task: Write  a program that takes an ASCII image as input and outputs its average.**

*Note Integers are rounded by function `floor(x+0.5)` or similar function - in other words, round halves upwards.*

Comment: What happens if the width is odd?

Comment: @KennyLau " If the picture ends before a section is complete, imagine that there are spaces there." I think that cover the case when the width is odd ;)

Comment: Can we assume the height will always be even ?

Comment: If not, will the height always be greater than one?

Comment: Can we just truncate decimal places instead of rounding up or down?

Comment: @DenkerAffe No. That would be cheating. :P

Comment: I think the outoput `#` in the example should be `$`. Can you check all values?

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Nice catch. Will fix...

Comment: @Solver 34.5 rounds to 35, not to 34

Comment: What about two `%` and a two spaces? That's 34.5. Conventionally, if it's exactly half way you should round up to 35 `# ` but you have 34 `"` Which is allowable? `#` or `"` or both?

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Is this better now?

Comment: Just to clarify with expected behavior, a 7x7 image would act as an 8x8 image with spaces on the bottom and right edge? Therefore our output would also be 8x8?

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 159 bytes

```js
document.write("<pre>"+(

// --- Solution ---
s=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>(a=String.fromCharCode([t=0,1,l=s.search`
`+1,l+1].map(o=>t+=(n=s.charCodeAt(p=i+o-i%l%2-(i/l|0)%2*l))>32?n:32)|t/4+.5))+(++p%l?"":a))
// ----------------

)(`%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Hello,    %
%    world! %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%`))
```

Takes a multiline string as input.

Comment: Running on Firefox, this produces incorrect output.

Comment: @Trebuchette Ah, I misinterpreted the space rule. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
2thZCO32XEoYmYocGZy2/Xke2t3$Y"
```

Input is a 2D char array, with rows separated by `;`.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MnRoWkNPMzJYRW9ZbVlvY0daeTIvWGtlMnQzJFki&input=WyclJSUlJSUlJSUlJSUlJzsnJSBIZWxsbywgICAgJSc7JyUgICAgd29ybGQhICUnOyclJSUlJSUlJSUlJSUlJ10)

#### Explanation

```
2th     % push array [2 2]
ZC      % take input implicitly. Arrange distinct 2x2 blocks as columns, padding with 0
O32XE   % replace 0 by 32 (space)
oYm     % convert to number. Take mean of each column
Yoc     % round. Convert to char
GZy     % size of input in the 2 dimensions
2/Xk    % divide each dimension by 2, and round up to account for the padding
e       % reshape into image with half original size in each dimension
2t3$Y"  % replicate by a factor of 2 in each dimension. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 58 bytes

```
J2A,lQlhQV:0GJ
Ksm*C+csmsm?&<kG<bHC@@Qkb32hBdhBN4 .5J:0HJK
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J2A%2ClQlhQV%3A0GJ%0AKsm*C%2Bcsmsm%3F%26%3CkG%3CbHC%40%40Qkb32hBdhBN4+.5J%3A0HJK&input=%5B%22%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%22%2C+%22%25+Hello%2C++++%25%22%2C+%22%25++++world!+%25%22%2C+%22%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%25%22%5D&debug=0)

Comment: The bonus is not there anymore

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <s>382</s> <s>376</s> <s>367</s> <s>353</s> 348 bytes

```
r="\n"o=... n=o:find(r)-1
l=n+n%2
a=o:gsub(r,(n~=l and" "or"")..r).." "..(#o//(l+1)%2<1 and r..(" "):rep(l)or"")print(a:gsub("()([^\n])(.)",function(p,m,c)t=p//(l+1)%2==0return string.char(math.floor((m:byte()+c:byte()+(t and a:sub(p+l+1,p+l+1)or a:sub(p-l,p-l)):byte()+(t and a:sub(p+l+2,p+l+2)or a:sub(p-l-1,p-l-1)):byte())/4+.5)):rep(2)end).."")
```

Works on the command line; accepts a string like the test case.

Comment: Care to include an ungolfed version?

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>235</s> 230 bytes

```
->i{i=i.split($/).map{|s|s.bytes+[s.size%2>0?32:0]}
w=i[0].size;h=i.size;h+=h%2;r=[[]]*h
(h/2).times{|y|y*=2
(w/2).times{|x|x*=2
c=((i[y][x,2]+(i[y+1]||[32]*w)[x,2]).inject(:+)/4.0).round.chr
r[y+1]=r[y]+=[c,c]}}
r.map(&:join)*$/}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 319 bytes

```python
def f(A):
 L,R,S=len,range,A.split('\n')
 if L(S[0])%2:S=[s+' 'for s in S]
 m=L(S[0])
 if L(S)%2:S+=[' '*m]
 C=[chr(int(sum(map(ord,[S[i][j],S[i+1][j],S[i][j+1],S[i+1][j+1]]))/4.0+0.5))for i in R(0,L(S),2)for j in R(0,m,2)]
 f=t='';i=0
 while i<L(C):
    t+=C[i]*2
    i+=1
    if i%(m/2)<1:f+=(t+'\n')*2;t=''
 f=f[:-1]
 print f
```

2nd indentation is tabs.

Stuff before `C` is padding, `C` is the averaging process to single letters and rest is output

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>180</s> <s>158</s> <s>148</s> <s>128 + 4</s> 124 + 4 = 128 bytes

Run with `$ ruby -nl` (+4 bytes for `-nl` flags). Takes input on STDIN.

```ruby
y,x=x,$_.scan(/..?/)
(puts [x.zip(y).map{|c|(("%2s"*2%c).bytes.reduce(:+)/4.0).round.chr*2}*""]*2
y,x=x,[])if$.%2<1||$<.eof?
```

See it on ideone: http://ideone.com/brmP3L

### Ungolfed & explanation

Per `man ruby`, the `-n` flag "[c]auses Ruby to assume the following loop around your script ... `while gets ... end`". The special variable `$_` contains the last line read by `gets`. The `-l` flag removes the `\n` from each line, equivalent to `$_.chop!`.

```ruby
y, x = x, $_.scan(/..?/)

( puts [
    x.zip(y).map {|c|
      (("%2s" * 2 % c).bytes.reduce(:+) / 4.0).round.chr * 2
    } * ""
  ] * 2
  y, x = x, []
) if $. % 2 < 1 || $<.eof?
```

The special variable `$.` is the number of lines that have been read so far, and `$<` is STDIN. The pairs of characters from every second line gets zipped with the previous line's. The format string `%2s%2s` combines the characters and pads it with spaces, then the characters are averaged.

Comment: `w=s=~/$/` is shorter for calculating initial width. Also just return the calculated string instead of printing because that counts as output

Answer (score 0):

### R, <s>433</s> 399 bytes

```
y=scan(,'',sep="\n")
h=nchar(y[1])
v=length(y)
p=function(x)paste(x,collapse="")
if(h%%2){y=sapply(y,function(x)paste0(x," "));h=h+1}
if(v%%2){y=c(y,p(rep(" ",h)));v=v+1}
z=matrix(unlist(lapply(y,function(x)strtoi(charToRaw(x),16))),ncol=h,byrow=T)
a=array(,c(v,h))
for(i in 1:(v/2)){for(j in 1:(h/2)){r=2*i-1:0;s=2*j-1:0;a[r,s]=rawToChar(as.raw(floor(mean(z[r,s])+.5)))}}
cat(apply(a,1,p),sep="\n")
```

I am getting desperate because this thing seems to be non-competing as heck. It prints

```
$$>>II99######
$$>>II99######
$$##88KKGG####
$$##88KKGG####
```

for the test case.

If you feed in the 7×3

```
%%%%%%%
Example
%%%%%%%
```

the output will be

```
BBFFJJ33
BBFFJJ33
######!!
######!!
```

because of the divisibility by 2 etc. etc.

Ungolfed:

```
y <- scan(, '', sep="\n") # Read STDIN and make it a character vector
h <- nchar(y[1]) # Get line width: how many chars per line
v <- length(y)   # Get array height: how many lines
p <- function(x) paste(x, collapse="") # A function that merges a vector of strings
if (h%%2) {y <- sapply(y, function(x) paste0(x, " ")); h=h+1} # If height is odd, add an empty line
if (v%%2) {y <- c(y, p(rep(" ", h))); v=v+1} # If width is odd, add an empty column
z <- matrix(unlist(lapply(y, function(x) strtoi(charToRaw(x), 16))), ncol=h, byrow=T)
# z now stores ASCII codes in a matrix; analogous to C strtol
a <- array(, dim=c(v,h)) # Reserve an array for the final result
for (i in 1:(v/2)) {
  for(j in 1:(h/2)) {
    r <- 2*i - 1:0 # Range of rows to average
    s <- 2*j - 1:0 # Range of columns to average
    a[r, s] <- rawToChar(as.raw(floor(mean(z[r, s]) + .5))) # Average, round, convert the ASCII codes
  } # and write them to the same place as in the original array
}
cat(apply(a, 1 , p), sep="\n") # Prints the array row-wise (index 1 for rows)
```

Just look how it handles this one gorgeous example (courtesy of chris.com):

```
                                                M$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$RMMMMM8MMX    
                                               <$$$$$$$$$$$$R????!!?MMMR$RMMh. 
                                              :M$$$$$$$R?!!~~~~!!!!!!!MMM$$$$X 
                                             :M$$$$$$$X!~~~   ~~~~~!!MM8$MM$$M!
                                           :!XM$$$$$$R!~~~~~  ~~~~~!!M$$$$$$$R!
                                          <!XM$$$$$$MR!~~~~ ~~ ~:!!<:!M$$$$$$$!
                                         '<!XMBQQRMMMMX:::~~~<!?!!~~!!!!$$$M!$X
                                         ~!!MM$$$$$M8R!!!?!:~!!M$f?!~~~!M$8HXX?
                                       <!!!XMM$$$$$MMRM$$!~!~~~~~~~~~~~!XM?!!M!
                                      <!!!!XMM$$M$$MM$M!!~~~ ~~~ ~  :~!!!X!~~R!
                                      !!!!XMMM$MMMMMMMM!!~~~ ~~~~  ~~~!!!X~~X!~
                                      '~~!!MMMM@MMMX!!MM!:~!!!~~  `~~~~!!XXXX~ 
                                        ~!!!XMMMMMMMM!MMM!~~~~:: <<~~~~!!$$R!  
                                        '!!!!MM888M$MXMMM!!!!()!!~~~~~<!X$$$>  
                                         ~!!!M???M$MRRMM$X<~!!!!~~~~~:!XN$$M   
                                          ~!!!!!M$$$$@$@$$!!~~'  ~~:XH8$$$WR   
                                          !!!!MM$RM$RRMMMM?t!:::XX8$$$$$$$$>   
                                         ~~!!MMM$$$$$WX!!!!!!$$$$$$$RR$$$R"    
                                       '  <!!MT!!!~~~!#BX!!!~~?T#?!!!M$$$X.    
                                         <!!!!~~~~~~~~~?$!!!~~~~~~:!M$$$$MXH:  
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~!M&!!!~~~<!!X$$$$$$$R$W>
                                        <~~~~~~~~    '~~!$!!!!!!!!MMRM$R?#!!$N!
                                       x~~~~~~~~~    ~~~!MX!!!!!!?!M!M!~~:!!$B!
                                      M!~~~~~~~~~~  <~~:!$R!!!!!!!X!!!~~!!~!RR!
                                    :M!~~~~~~~~~~~ `~~~!X$R!!!!!!!!~~~:!!~~tMM!
                                   dR!!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!M$R!!!!!!!~!!!!!!~~@$@~
                                  tR!!!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!M$R!!!!!!!!!!!!!~~!$$E~
                                 d!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!$$X!!!!!!!!!!!!~~~X$$!~
                                8R~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~<!X$$!!!!!!!!!!!<~~~!MR$~~
                               8$~~~~~~~!~~~~~~~~~~~<!!$$R!!!MX!!!!~~~~~<XR$!~<
                             :$$!~~~~~~!!~~~~~~~~~~~!!M$$!!!!MM!!!~~~~~<!8$F~<!
                          .x8$$$!~~~~::!~~~~~~~~~~~!!X$$$!!!!MM!!~~~~~!!M$R~~~!
               .::xxxnHW8$$$$$$$$$$$$$$!!~~~~~~~~~~<!@$$X!!!!MM~~~~~<!!X$E~~~~!
          :t$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$!!~~~~~~~~~~!X$$$X~!!!MX~~~~~!!X$$~~~~!!
       ~~~~#R$$$$$RR8$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$!!~~~~~~~~~<!M$$$B~!!!M!~~~~~!X$$!~~~~!!
     ~~~~~~~~?$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$!!~~~~~~~~~!!$$$$$X!!X$!~~~~!X$$R~~~~<!f
  :~~~~~~~~~`~?$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$!!~~~~~~~~!!X$$$$$$X!M$~~~<!W$$R~~~~~!! 
 ~~~~~~~~~~  ~~M$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$!!~~~~~~~~!!M$$$$$$$$$Bid$$$$$$!~~~~~!! 
!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$!~~~~~~~~~!!$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$!~~~~~~!~ 
!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~M$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$!:~~~~~~~<!X$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$!~~~~~~!!  
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$R!!:~~~~~~!!M$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"XR~~~~~~~!!  
~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!!$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$R!<!~~~~~!!!X$$$$$$$$$$$P~  !~~~~~~~!!   
~~~~~~~~~~~<!!!!!$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$X!!~~~~~<!!!@#""`           ~~~~~~~~!!   
~~~~~~~~~~~!!!!!X$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$X!~~~~~~!!!                '~~~~~~~!!    
~~~~~~~~~~~<!!!!M$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$X!~~~~~!!!f                '~~~~~~<!!    
~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$R!~~~~~~!!!                 '~~~~~<!!>    
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!M$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$" !~~~~~!!!!                 ~~~~~~!!!     
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$R~ .!~~~~~!!!                  ~~~~~!!!!     
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!$$$$$$$$$$$$$*?!!!~!!~~~~<!!~                  ~~~~!!!!!     
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!$$$$$$$$*"~!!!!!!!!!~~~~!!!                  <~~~:!!!!!     
!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!M$$$$#~~~~~~~~~~~!!~~~~~!!                   ~~~~~~~!!!     
!<~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!R"~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!~~~~<!!                  '~~~~~~<!!      
!<~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!~~~~~!!!X:                ~~~~~~~!!~      
!!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!!~~~~~~~~~~~~<!!~~~~!!!9$MX:              ~~~~~~<!!       
!!!!!~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!!:~~~~~~~~~~~!!~~~~~!!X$$$X!~            '~~~~~~!!~       
!!!!!!~~~~~~~~~~~<!!!!!!~~~~~~~~~~!!~~~~!!!M$$R!~~~~          ~~~~~~!!!        
!!!!!!!<~~~~~~~~~~~!!!!!!!:<:~~~~~!!~~~~!!X$$R!~~~~~~         ~~~~~~!!         
!!!!!!!!~~~~~~~~~~<!!!!!!!!!!!!!<!!!~~~~!!@$$!~~~~~~~~        ~~~~~!!~         
!!!!!!!!!~~~~~~~~:<!!!!X!!!!!!!!!!!!~~~!!X$$!~~~~~~~~~~~~:   '~~~~~!!          
'!!!!!!!!!!~~~~~~~!!!!!!?!!!!!!!!!!!~~<!!M$M!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ '~~~~~!~          
 !!!!!!!!!!\~~~~~~~>!!!!  `"MMMHX!!~~~<!!$R!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~<~~~~!!           
  !!!!!!!!!!<~~~~~<!!!!!   .::<!!!!<~~!!X8X!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!           
  `X!!!!!!!!~~~~~!<!!!!!!!!!!!!~~!!\~~!!M$MX!:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~<!~~!>           
  !X!!!!!!!!~!!:!!!!!!!!!!~!!!:~~!!~~~!!$M!~~!!<~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!!!            
  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!:!!~~:!9R!~~~~~~!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~<!!f            
 'CHAT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!~~~!!MX~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!X
```

After:

```
                                              ''..$$$$$$$$$$662266??MMIIDDEE66  
                                              ''..$$$$$$$$$$662266??MMIIDDEE66  
                                            ''>>$$$$$$<<WWOOOOggPP88,,HH99..;;  
                                            ''>>$$$$$$<<WWOOOOggPP88,,HH99..;;  
                                          ..HH..$$$$EEPP~~ggOOggVV??22..$$$$00!!
                                          ..HH..$$$$EEPP~~ggOOggVV??22..$$$$00!!
                                        99((PP77;;CCII5555VVVV4433WWPP88..<<==66
                                        99((PP77;;CCII5555VVVV4433WWPP88..<<==66
                                      ..!!==MM$$..99DD8899gggg~~ggOOmm88HH@@PP!!
                                      ..!!==MM$$..99DD8899gggg~~ggOOmm88HH@@PP!!
                                      ::88EEMM@@MMPP77BB??gg88~~88__~~88==kkTT88
                                      ::88EEMM@@MMPP77BB??gg88~~88__~~88==kkTT88
                                        ::!!EEHHCCCCEEMM77PPQQ00??nn~~??0000((  
                                        ::!!EEHHCCCCEEMM77PPQQ00??nn~~??0000((  
                                        8888,,00??..BB@@11??PP""ggmmVV55//GG    
                                        8888,,00??..BB@@11??PP""ggmmVV55//GG    
                                        8888,,MM00..HHEE77==((//>>));;$$00))    
                                        8888,,MM00..HHEE77==((//>>));;$$00))    
                                      ""''((,,\\PP~~ggII00!!~~ddXX''88$$;;<<''  
                                      ""''((,,\\PP~~ggII00!!~~ddXX''88$$;;<<''  
                                        VV~~~~~~ggOO99gg..!!88PP((EE::00++..;;((
                                        VV~~~~~~ggOO99gg..!!88PP((EE::00++..;;((
                                      BB~~~~~~~~gg  VVmm--;;!!!!))::,,gg??88CC!!
                                      BB~~~~~~~~gg  VVmm--;;!!!!))::,,gg??88CC!!
                                  11??PP~~~~~~~~~~__~~PP;;::!!!!!!PPPP''PPll@@88
                                  11??PP~~~~~~~~~~__~~PP;;::!!!!!!PPPP''PPll@@88
                                11YYPPgg~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!..;;!!!!!!!!!!88~~00,,OO
                                11YYPPgg~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!..;;!!!!!!!!!!88~~00,,OO
                              &&KK~~~~~~gg~~~~~~~~~~FF0000!!,,//!!88VV~~MMEEPP??
                              &&KK~~~~~~gg~~~~~~~~~~FF0000!!,,//!!88VV~~MMEEPP??
                          ::..$$PP~~mm??gg~~~~~~~~gg//..##!!777788~~~~??33OOnn!!
                          ::..$$PP~~mm??gg~~~~~~~~gg//..##!!777788~~~~??33OOnn!!
          <<""&&//NNLL::))$$$$$$$$$$$$##PP~~~~~~~~VV77$$TT!!77hh~~~~((==CC~~gg!!
          <<""&&//NNLL::))$$$$$$$$$$$$##PP~~~~~~~~VV77$$TT!!77hh~~~~((==CC~~gg!!
    88gg~~ggMM$$$$;;))$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$##PP~~~~~~~~((..$$OO!!;;PP~~gg==00gg~~??22
    88gg~~ggMM$$$$;;))$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$##PP~~~~~~~~((..$$OO!!;;PP~~gg==00gg~~??22
88mm~~~~~~gg__LL$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$##PP~~~~~~PP::$$$$$$0066rrAA00$$\\~~~~!!  
88mm~~~~~~gg__LL$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$##PP~~~~~~PP::$$$$$$0066rrAA00$$\\~~~~!!  
PP~~~~~~~~~~~~~~..$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$##mm~~~~~~??00$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$99~~~~gg88  
PP~~~~~~~~~~~~~~..$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$##mm~~~~~~??00$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$99~~~~gg88  
~~~~~~~~~~~~gg!!##$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$::..~~~~gg!!;;$$$$$$$$$$FF""RR~~~~~~88    
~~~~~~~~~~~~gg!!##$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$::..~~~~gg!!;;$$$$$$$$$$FF""RR~~~~~~88    
~~~~~~~~~~VV!!!!00$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$==gg~~~~((!!))!!00        ""~~~~~~gg!!    
~~~~~~~~~~VV!!!!00$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$==gg~~~~((!!))!!00        ""~~~~~~gg!!    
~~~~~~~~~~nn88!!..$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$00FF~~~~PP!!22              $$~~~~nn((((    
~~~~~~~~~~nn88!!..$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$00FF~~~~PP!!22              $$~~~~nn((((    
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!..$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$FF$$PP~~~~!!!!                OO~~~~88!!      
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!..$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$FF$$PP~~~~!!!!                OO~~~~88!!      
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~gg!!##$$$$$$&&::$$))!!88PP~~VV!!88                VV~~??!!!!      
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~gg!!##$$$$$$&&::$$))!!88PP~~VV!!88                VV~~??!!!!      
??~~~~~~~~~~~~~~PP,,//QQgg~~~~~~~~gg!!~~~~??!!                ""~~~~~~??!!      
??~~~~~~~~~~~~~~PP,,//QQgg~~~~~~~~gg!!~~~~??!!                ""~~~~~~??!!      
((~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!88~~~~~~~~~~~~??PP~~gg!!66@@''            OO~~~~nn!!88      
((~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!88~~~~~~~~~~~~??PP~~gg!!66@@''            OO~~~~nn!!88      
!!!!88~~~~~~~~~~nn!!!!??~~~~~~~~~~!!~~~~88::$$<<ggOO          hh~~~~8888        
!!!!88~~~~~~~~~~nn!!!!??~~~~~~~~~~!!~~~~88::$$<<ggOO          hh~~~~8888        
!!!!!!((~~~~~~~~~~??!!!!!!..??PPVV!!~~~~!!88//gg~~~~gg        ~~~~gg88          
!!!!!!((~~~~~~~~~~??!!!!!!..??PPVV!!~~~~!!88//gg~~~~gg        ~~~~gg88          
##!!!!!!88gg~~~~mm((!!//))!!!!!!!!!!~~??::..PP~~~~~~~~~~mmOO$$~~~~PP88          
##!!!!!!88gg~~~~mm((!!//))!!!!!!!!!!~~??::..PP~~~~~~~~~~mmOO$$~~~~PP88          
  !!!!!!!!00nn~~~~FF!!!!  44DD==//??~~((55;;~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~nn~~~~!!            
  !!!!!!!!00nn~~~~FF!!!!  44DD==//??~~((55;;~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~nn~~~~!!            
  LL!!!!!!!!ggVV88((!!!!!!88!!VVPPGG~~!!99QQ??VV~~~~~~~~~~~~~~??PP((            
  LL!!!!!!!!ggVV88((!!!!!!88!!VVPPGG~~!!99QQ??VV~~~~~~~~~~~~~~??PP((            
""3366!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!''ggVV22RR~~~~~~gg~~~~~~~~~~~~VV//22            
""3366!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!''ggVV22RR~~~~~~gg~~~~~~~~~~~~VV//22
```